# Domain administrator account has weird behaviours

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, windows-domain

I have a domain account that has administrator privileges on the OU, let's say A. I logged in the computer with that admin account, install Office without any hickups. But then I need to run `chkdsk` the `command promt` tell me I need elevated privileges to do it.

I checked:

1. The computer is joined to the domain. Both the properties of `My
   computer` and the presence of the computer name in the OU shows
   that.
2. The Administrator group of that computer contained my admin account.

The weird point is I can install some programs which write on OS partition (and they don't complain anything). But when I launch `cmd` with my admin account (use `runas` or `shift+right click`) I don't have elevated privileges on that session.

Please tell me what's wrong?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: This behavior is intentional

Comment: I feel it's weird because in the OU I manage, only 2 computers have this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I guess UAC is activated on thoses workstations,
you might try to run with maximum elevated privileges your command prompt.

I would suggest the use of [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) for this.

The command to run a cmd prompt with maximum privileges would then be :

```
psexec -h cmd
```

Then try again your command in this command shell.

Hope it will help you.